# java database failed to connect

Tags: java, sql, mysql, jdbc

I have a trouble that the connection fails and it tells me I have no driver for MySQL although I have here is the code

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled7</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies><!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aliaa</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

```java
package com.aliaa.jdbc;

import com.aliaa.jdbc.dao.DBConnection;

import java.sql.Connection;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Connection con= DBConnection.getConnection();
        if (con ==null){
            System.out.println("connection failed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("CONNECTION success!");
        }
    }
}
```

```sql
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS jdbc_db;
CREATE DATABASE jdbc_db;
USE jdbc_db;
CREATE TABLE students
(
     id         INT(15) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name       VARCHAR(30),
     gender     BOOLEAN,
     birth_date DATE,
     grade      REAL
);
```

```java
package com.aliaa.jdbc.dao;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {
    private static final String HOST="127.0.0.1";
    private static final int PORT =3306;

    private static final String DB_NAME="jdbc_db";
    private static final String USERNAME ="root";
    private static final String PASSWORD="";

    private static Connection connection;
    public static Connection getConnection(){
        try {
            connection=DriverManager.getConnection(String.format("jdbc:mysql://%s:%d%s",HOST,PORT,DB_NAME),USERNAME,PASSWORD);
        } catch (SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
        return connection;
    }
}
```

The database is made and I can access it on PHPMyAdmin

The error

> Process finished with exit code 0

I tried to download another drivers and add them to the DAO file, but it did not work. I changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost, it did not work either.

Comment: Your pom.xml doesn't seem to include the MySQL Connector/J driver.

Comment: Your pom.xml is wrong. Look on the Maven repo site for the correct dependency to use for the connector-j driver

Comment: As an aside, _"Process finished with exit code 0"_ is not an error. If you get an error, post the actual exception stacktrace.

Comment: yes it is exception stacktrace but it seems it wasn't copied and  i have downloaded MySQL Connector/J driver.

Comment: *and i have downloaded MySQL Connector/J driver.* Not right. Maven does the 'downloading' *for* you. [I already mentioned what you should do](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.33).